# Finding the missing charge

Tags: particle-physics, charge, time, particle-detectors

I'm doing a lab report. I have to find the charge integrating some pulses. Unfortunately some pulses are partially saturated (see the photo). My idea is trying to find the charge in function of something from the "full pulses" and find the missing charge. I would like to this in python. Anyonr has any idea? I can't solve this problem.
The detector is a SiPM, and on the x axis there time and on the y axis there is the number of counts. The setting consists of a radioactive source (sodium) which emits photons that impact on those SiPM.

[image]

Comment: What kind of detector? Is the decay time constant of the pulses fixed, or is there variable charge collection time involved?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are the axes labels

Comment: I added some extra informations

Comment: @JohnDoty Variable charge collection time involved.